# With the weather is getting cold, I have problems starting my 2001 C240 Mercedes

Tags: starting, mercedes-benz, c240

I have a 2001 Mercedes C240.  Since the weather has been getting cold lately, I have had a problem starting the car. When I try to start the car, it makes no sound. After several attempts, the engine will start.

A local mechanic says that the starter is ok.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your best bet is get your car scanned for ODBII errors first and see if you any specific errors related to the vehicle and it's various components.  You can goto an auto parts store and have them scan your car for codes with no charge.  They are trying to sell parts and this is an effective method to do just that.

Without additional information it would be very difficult to assist you in what the root cause of your problem is.

Comment: As well, click this link and take the tour of the site to see how it works.  Cheers and thanks for the question.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you hear the fuel pump prime when the ignition is in the 'On' position?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: is that a diesel or a gasoline (petrol) engine?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at the battery. If the terminals are not nice and snug and preferably coated with an anti-corrosion solution, they can appear to be connected but not actually be connected enough to fire the starter.

Also, today's modern batteries are Calcuim based, which makes them lose capacity abruptly if they've ever gone flat. Typically though, the cold weather just makes the car harder to start, and the battery struggles. But you are not describing that particular case as you say there's no noise.

It is odd you don't hear a noise. Here's another possible cause:

Mercedes use a BUS system to activate various electrics. The A-class was notorious for this sudden misbehavior, see [this article](http://jasoceania.co.nz/articles/class-mercedes-starters-and-their-solenoids). Your auto mechanic may not have noticed the electronic solenoid.

I suspect the cold weather has simply caused the fault to become more evident, rather than being the cause itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few tips for starting a car in winter:https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/how-to-start-a-car-in-cold-weather

Other people do have these problems

Comment: Please include a summary of the information of the link. What if the information on that ink changes or gets deleted?

Comment: Link not ink. Link.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a relay in the starter system that is getting balky when its cold.